# Raws into Strings in Columns - only if two subsequent are unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

How to modify the code below to have final cluster string only with ErrorCodes which do not duplicate the previous one, so for line 3 returns only one C (skip second C) and for line 1 A,C,A,B (skip second A because of neighbouring duplication).

```
    DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    [Case] INT,
    ErrorCode CHAR(1),
    [Date] varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES
(1, 'A', '2018-01-25'),
(1, 'A', '2018-01-15'),
(1, 'C', '2018-01-15'),
(1, 'A', '2018-01-15'),
(1, 'A', '2018-01-15'),
(1, 'B', '2018-01-15'),
(2, 'D', '2018-01-26'),
(2, 'A', '2018-01-26'),
(2, 'D', '2018-01-25'),
(2, 'C', '2018-01-24'),
(2, 'C', '2018-01-24');

SELECT *
FROM @table1;

SELECT tabel2.[Case],
       tabel2.[Date],
       STUFF(
       (
           SELECT ', ' + ErrorCode
           FROM @table1 t1
           WHERE t1.[Case] = tabel2.[Case]
                 AND t1.[Date] = tabel2.[Date]
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ),
       1,
       1,
       ''
            ) AS [ErrorCode]
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT [Case], [Date] FROM @table1) AS tabel2
ORDER BY tabel2.[Case],
         tabel2.[Date];
```

Comment: As I've told you in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54397451/5089204) , there is no such thing as *neighbour* data. For example all the values for case 1 on `2018-01-15` (which is ACAAB in the provided sample) **do not have an implicit sort order...** The same query might return  100 times with ACAAB, but suddenly you'd get `AAABC`, or `BAACA`, or any other combination... In short: With the given data **this is not possible**. If there is a sorting column *as inserted* (like an additional `IDENTITY` value), you can read about `LAG()` and `LEAD()`.

Comment: *Please* don't use `varchar` to store dates. Use `date` or `datetime2(0)` or another date type.. That `varchar(20)` takes more space than any date type and doesn't guarantee the contents are valid. Nothing prevents someone from inserting `2018-24-01`

Comment: Besides, `neighbouring` in what order? Unless you specify an order, the results will return in *random* order, whatever is cheapest for the server. Unless an order is explicitly specified the first line can easily contain `ACABA`, `ABACA` or `AAABC`. Parallel query processing will return results in random order.

Comment: How you you tell if the 2nd row is earlier or later than 4th one (both have same dates).

Comment: What I mean by order: order is defined by direction of rows being processed: from upper raws to lower ones so for example for 2018-01-15: A C A A B and I would like to maintain the same order but just eliminate second A: A C A B.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

First off, you better have a primary key or unique constraint in your table that uniquely identifies each row, that is set theory - 101 :). If you don't, which I assumed, here's how I added PK or Row Number:

```
;WITH Mytable AS 
(
   SELECT [case], [date], ErrorCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select NULL)) as rn
   FROM table1 
)

SELECT * FROM Mytable
```

Now we know the sequence of each row which is very important and required by your task, find next value of each row using sub-query:

```
,nextTable AS
(
    SELECT *, (SELECT errorcode 
                FROM Mytable mt2
                WHERE mt2.rn = mt1.rn+1 
                AND mt1.[Case] = mt2.[case] 
                AND mt1.[date] = mt2.[date]) as NextErrorCode
    FROM Mytable mt1
)
```

Then finally, compare them to each other with CASE clause, and if it is duplicate, then eliminate it:

```
,final AS
(
SELECT[case], [date],
    CASE WHEN  ErrorCode = ISNULL(NextErrorCode, '') THEN NULL ELSE ErrorCode END as NewErrorCode
FROM nextTable
WHERE CASE WHEN  ErrorCode = ISNULL(NextErrorCode, '') THEN NULL ELSE ErrorCode END IS NOT NULL 
)
```

And the easy part, concatenate rows into strings any way you wish:

```
SELECT @str =  COALESCE(@str + ',','') + NewErrorCode
FROM final
WHERE [case] = @case AND [date] = @date
```

Final code looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_groupConcat
(
@case int,
@date date
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @str varchar(200) 

;WITH Mytable AS 
(
    SELECT [case], [date], ErrorCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select NULL)) as rn
    FROM table1 
)
,nextTable AS
(
    SELECT *, (SELECT errorcode 
                FROM Mytable mt2
                WHERE mt2.rn = mt1.rn+1 AND mt1.[Case] = mt2.[case] AND mt1.[date] = mt2.[date]) as NextErrorCode
    FROM Mytable mt1
)
,final AS
(
    SELECT[case], [date],
    CASE WHEN  ErrorCode = ISNULL(NextErrorCode, '') THEN NULL ELSE ErrorCode END as NewErrorCode
    FROM nextTable
    WHERE CASE WHEN  ErrorCode = ISNULL(NextErrorCode, '') THEN NULL ELSE ErrorCode END IS NOT NULL 
)

SELECT @str =  COALESCE(@str + ',','') + NewErrorCode
FROM final
WHERE [case] = @case AND [date] = @date

RETURN(@str)
END
```

Apply the function to your table:

```
SELECT [case], [date], dbo.fn_groupConcat([case],[date]) as ErrorCode
FROM table1
GROUP BY [case], [date]

 ---------------------------------
|case |   date      |  ErrorCode  |
 ---------------------------------|
| 1   |  2018-01-15 |   A,C,A,B   |
| 1   |  2018-01-25 |   A         |
| 2   |  2018-01-24 |   C         |
| 2   |  2018-01-25 |   D         |
| 2   |  2018-01-26 |   D,A       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed the `INNER` `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ErrorCode
           FROM @table1 t1
           WHERE t1.[Case] = tabel2.[Case]
                 AND t1.[Date] = tabel2.[Date]
           FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: The OP has posted a [very similiar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54397451/5089204), where I've provided exactly the same solution. But in this case the OP does not want to get a distinct list, but just reduce neighbourings siblings. You might want to read my comment, before you invest more time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT  [Case],
        [Date]
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(ErrorCode AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @table1 
         WHERE [Case] = t.[Case] and [Date] = t.[Date]
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM @Table1 t
GROUP BY [Case], [Date]
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/IGEOT35812).

To get only unique values you need to use `Distinct` keyword as shown below.

```
SELECT  [Case],
        [Date]
       ,STUFF((SELECT Distinct ', ' + CAST(ErrorCode AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @table1 
         WHERE [Case] = t.[Case] and [Date] = t.[Date]
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM @Table1 t
GROUP BY [Case], [Date]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to satisfy OP's requirement. Your first query produces the same thing OP is getting, and your second query removes all duplications, rather than just those where the dupes are adjacent.